# How i can split a Email in Django

Tags: django, forms, split

Good morning
I've been sitting for 5 hours on what should be a simple problem. I would be grateful if you could end my suffering.
It is about a dashboard page. I want the user to be greeted with his name (Hello, ....) after he has registered with his email address. When registering, the email address is always the same, name.example@hotmail.de. I want to split the email address and display only the name, but I can only manage to display the whole email address.

view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login') 
def Example_dashboard(request):
    form = MembersForm()
    current_user = request.user #current_user.split is not working!  
  
    context = {'form': form, "cunrrent_user": current_user}
    return render(request, 'example_dashboard.html', context)
```

html

```
<p>Welcome, {{ current_user}}  </p>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{ form }}
```

models.py

```
class Members(models.Model):
  email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  passwort = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class MembersForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Members

        fields = ["studiengang", "kategorien"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user = request.user #current_user.split is not working!
```

It will not work becouse `request.user` is a `User` object not a **String** you can't split user object instead you can do like this to split user's email.

```
@login_required(login_url='login') 
def Example_dashboard(request):
    form = MembersForm()
    current_user = request.user
    name = current_user.email.split('@')[0] # or .split('.example@hotmail.de')[0]
    context = {'form': form, "cunrrent_user": current_user}
    return render(request, 'example_dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: has worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can make this possible by using [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method

After `current_user = request.user`, Try this:

```py
current_user = current_user.split('@')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Because of `request.user` is `None`. That's why you can't split an email.

```
current_user = request.POST.get(‘email’)
user_name = current_user.split('@')[0]
```